# Jquery fill object like array

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

This should be pretty easy but I'm a little confused here. I want to fill this object:

```
var obj = { 2:some1, 14:some2, three:some3, XX:some4, five:some5 };
```

but in the start I have this:

```
var obj = {};
```

I´m making a for but I don't know how to add, I was using push(), but is not working. Any help?

Comment: So your keys are not in order, and have different name schemes?

Comment: Yes, They are not the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `.push()` into a javascript OBJECT, since it uses custom keys instead of index.  The way of doing this is pretty much like this:

```
var obj = {};

for (var k = 0; k<10; k++) {
    obj['customkey'+k] = 'some'+k;
}
```

This would return:

```
obj {
    customkey0 : 'some0',
    customkey1 : 'some1',
    customkey2 : 'some2',
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind, an array: `['some1','some2']` is basicly like and object:
`{
0 : 'some1',
1 : 'some2'
}`
Where an object replaces the "index" (0,1,etc) by a STRING key.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`push()` is for use in arrays, but you're creating a object.

You can add properties to an object in a few different ways:

```
obj.one = some1;
```

or

```
obj['one'] = some1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple function like this:

```
 function pushVal(obj, value) {
     var index = Object.size(obj);
     //index is modified to be a string.
     obj[index] = value;
 }
```

Then in your code, when you want to add values to an object you can simply call:

```
  for(var i=0; i<someArray.length; i++) {
      pushVal(obj, someArray[i]);
   }
```

For info on the size function I used, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array). Note, it is possible to use the index from the for loop, however, if you wanted to add multiple arrays to this one object, my method prevents conflicting indices.

**EDIT**

Seeing that you changed your keys in your questions example, in order to create the object, you can use the following:

```
function pushVal(obj, value, key) {
     //index is modified to be a string.
     obj[key] = value;
 }

 or 

 obj[key] = value;
```

I'm not sure how you determine your key value, so without that information, I can't write a solution to recreate the object, (as is, they appear random).

Comment: Sounds good, but you could go "prototype" for that matter.  Something like 
Object.prototype.pushVal = function(index,value) {
   this[index] = value;
   return this;
}
and the you just have to go:
var obj = {}
obj.pushVal('some1','some value for some1');

The "return this" is only to make sure you can queue things up like this:
obj.pushVal('1','test').pushVal('2','another test')

Comment: I avoid prototype simply because Object.prototype is sensitive to change and one should always be very careful when modifying it.

Comment: true. Actually this one would've been problematic but it was just to show some other possible solutions.